# Plotting of a function

Tags: functions

$$F(x) = \begin{cases}
0 & \text{if } x < 0 \\
x^3/8 & \text{if } 0 \leq x< 2 \\
1 & \text{if } 2 \leq x < 3 \\
0 & \text{o.w.}
\end{cases}
$$

Now my question is while plotting the graph I understand that it is $0$ when $a<0$ & $a\geq 3$.
it is $1$ between $2$ & $3$.

However should I draw a straight line from the point $(3,1)$ to $(3,0)$ in the graph or should there be a gap/function jump?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_discontinuities#Jump_discontinuity

Comment: No you shouldn't. Use instead "open" and "closed" points, precisely draw a closed point at $(3,0)$ and an open point at $(3,1)$.

Answer (score 1):

Your function is discontinuous just only at $x=3$ as you can see in the graph of the function below (the point $(3,1)$ does not belong to the function).

[image]